# Django-Storages ('`data` must be bytes, received', <class 'str'>) when saving a model field

Tags: python, django, django-storage, python-django-storages

I read through the [django-storages docs](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) which suggest using the following to save files to cloud storage (GCS in my case):

```
>>> obj2 = Resume()
>>> obj2.pdf.save('django_test.txt', ContentFile('more content'))
>>> obj2.pdf
<FieldFile: tests/django_test_.txt>
>>> obj2.pdf.size
```

However, following the same logic, I'm struggling to save a Pandas DataFrame as a CSV using FileField object:

My code:

```
   df = load_some_df()
   print(df.head())
   # prints contents of df
   contents = ContentFile(df.to_csv(index=False, header=True))
   output_file_name = 'df.csv'

   instance = MyModel()
   instance.output_file.save(output_file_name, contents)
```

The above gives me the error:

```
('`data` must be bytes, received', <class 'str'>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `df.to_csv(index=False, header=True)` with `df.to_csv(index=False, header=True).encode('utf-8')`

Comment: It's good that you succeeded in solving your own problem, but it would be better to write a bit more about what you learned along the way and why the change matters.

Comment: I don't really know why this works. Since `ContentFile()` just as happily takes a Strings object. This is 3rd party `django-storages` issue, or so it seems. Locally, both options are valid.

Comment: It's an *internet* issue, by my parsing. You need to be able to serialize things to send them over the wire. You might ask why the library doesn't handle that internally; that's a question for their dev team.